# Tooltip - Won't hide on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have Tooltip implemented. While it does work, if I hover over too fast the tooltip doesn't disappear. Is there a way to ensure the tooltip hides on mouse out, or on click (for mobile friendly):

```
 // on mouse over, make a call to DB using AJAX and return results into tooltip
j$( '[data-toggle=tooltip]' ).on( 'mouseover', function( e ){
        var the_Tooltip = j$(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        var tour_ID = the_Tooltip.parent().find('.tour_ID').text();
        var tour_Date = the_Tooltip.parent().find('.tour_Date').text();
        var tour_Date_To = the_Tooltip.parent().find('.tour_Date-to').text();
        var data = {
          "action"    : "testing",
          "tour_ID"   : tour_ID,
          "tour_Date" : tour_Date,
          "tour_Date_To": tour_Date_To
        };
            j$.ajax( {
              url: '../include/vessel-count.php',
              dataType : 'json',
              type : 'POST',
              data: data,
              //cache: false,
              success : function( data ){
                j$(the_Tooltip).tooltip('hide').attr('data-original-title', data.vessel_Info).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
                //console.log("returned date: "+data.vessel_Info);
              },
              error: function (request) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
                console.log(request["vessel_Info"]);
              }  
            } );//end ajax
    });
```

I have tried adding in this but had no luck:

```
j$( '[data-toggle=tooltip]' ).on( 'mouseout', function( e ){
    j$(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Note - When you hover over and the tooltip works for the first time, it stays up. Everytime after that it works as expected.

Comment: Can you share the Fiddle ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I am unable to simulate using a fiddle. Not sure how to get it working using AJAX sorry

Comment: You are invoking `show()` after ajax success.. Why ?

Comment: on successful return, I want to see the results in the tooltip

Comment: I think it hides, but then your yet `incomplete ajax request`, completes and brings it back

Comment: @A_Singh I suspect that too. Is there a way to get around this? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "j" just before from "$" sign, your code will work. It's working for me.

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]' ).on( 'mouseout', function( e ){
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```